# json parse within angularjs filter causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a filter function which makes a synchronous ajax call. The callback of the function returns a json object which is then passed to a variable of the filter function which is then returned as the filter result. An infinite loop of ajax calls are made ONLY when the dataType of the ajax call is set to 'json'. When returning a string, there is no infinite loop.

Why does this code, when placed inside a filter function, cause a recursive infinite loop?

```
        var result;
        that = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/url/',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'get',
            success: function (links) {

                that.result = links;
            }
        });

        return that.result;
```

Comment: can you give more your code ex js & html ? and what doyou want to ask?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this doesn't look like a synchronous AJAX call - it looks like you're returning undefined and then setting it later.

Comment: I've amended the code to pass the ajax result to the var of the parent scope. The problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use synchronous ajax cals.
2. Do not use long time processing in filters = filters are called in each $digest cycle, so your long sync ajax call inside filter just freezing browser again and again.